# Mocking Express Chained Response with JEST

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, jestjs

I am pretty new to the jest and typescript, I am trying to create a small unit test for a controller function in jest

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express';

const healthCheck = (_req: Request, _res: Response) => {
  const value = _req.params.name ?? 'World!';
  return _res.status(200).json({ message: `Hello ${value}` });
};

export default healthCheck;
```

The unit test i wrote for the above function is

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express';

import healthCheck from './health.controller';

describe('Health Controller', () => {
  it('healthCheck should send 200 on an optional path param', () => {
    const req = { params: {} } as Request;
    const res = {
      json: jest.fn(),
      status: jest.fn(),
    } as unknown as Response;

    healthCheck(req, res);

    expect(res.status).toHaveBeenCalledWith(200);
  });
});
```

I am getting an error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'json' of undefined
>  8 |   return _res.status(200).json({ message: `Hello ${value}` });
```

why i am getting the `json` of undefined, even if i mock the property?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your mocks need a bit tweaking:

```js
const res = {} as unknown as Response;
res.json = jest.fn();
res.status = jest.fn(() => res); // chained
```

As @hellitsjoe pointed out, Express chains the call.

```js
_res.status(200).json({ message: `Hello ${value}` })
```

So your mocks need to return other mocks for everything to work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. When change according to your code, i am getting that 
TypeError: _res.status(...).json is not a function. why is this happening?

Comment: Ah, I think there is a bug in the code. Let me update accordingly.

Comment: Only way I found to properly mock out the chained status and json methods when testing express with Jest. Thanks @beautifulcoder

Answer (score 2):

Since you're calling `res.status().json()`, `json` should be a function on the return value of `status()`, rather than on `res`.

A popular library for this type of mocking is [`node-mocks-http`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-mocks-http), which gives you `req` and `res` objects to pass into handlers so you don't have to mock them yourself.